# AFNetworking returning invalid response object

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am considering using AFNetworking in one of my projects. But I have a problem.

Here is the code:

```
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
  //      manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        [manager GET:completeUrlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);


        } failure:nil];
```

The problem Is the respose object. It is a dictionary with only a value inside. The value is shown to be a NSObject!  That should actually be a NSDictionary with several key/value pairs.

Here is the raw json:

```
{

    "signInResponse": {
        "userName": "971777771554300",
        "duration": 315360000000,
        "token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "userId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "idleTimeout": 2592000000
    }

}
```

Why does the parser fail? Also I would like to note that the url does not end in ".json" as it is dinamically created.

Another small question: several resposes return json objects where the keys that need to be in the 
response dictionary are of the form "@importantKey" or "#key". I remmember that some parsers can't returns such keys in their response, is this a problem for AFNetworking?

Comment: How do you test the class of the response?  You mention a parser, but I don't see any parser code.

Comment: I see it in the debug window of XCOde. As I understand AFNetworking does both json requests and parsing..

Comment: cast the response into a dictionary: _yourNSDictionary = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

Comment: Why did you comment out setting the serializer? It's a needed step.

Answer (score 0):

if you use alamofire, this little snippet can help, maybe you need to do casting like this :

```
var innerData = data!["signInResponse"]!!
var innerData2 = innerData[0] 
var DataDict = (innerData2 as! NSDictionary) as Dictionary
self.userName   = DataDict["userName"]! as! String
```